# Dynamically added TableRows not in Rows collection on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've added TableRows via code-behind to a table. The rows render on the page, but on PostBack, the rows are no longer part of the collection. What is the trick to get these rows to persist so that I can use them on PostBack?

.ascx

```
<asp:Table id="OrderItemsTable" runat="server">
```

.ascx.cs

```
TableRow itemRow = new TableRow();

// Ticket Quantity
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
cell1.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
TextBox ticket1QuantityTextBox = new TextBox();
ticket1QuantityTextBox.Width = Unit.Pixel(30);
ticket1QuantityTextBox.MaxLength = 3;
ticket1QuantityTextBox.Attributes.Add("class", "OrderItemTicketQuantityTB");
ticket1QuantityTextBox.Text = item.Quantity.ToString();
cell1.Controls.Add(ticket1QuantityTextBox);
itemRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
...
OrderItemsTable.Rows.Add(itemRow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to construct the control tree with your dynamic controls in Page_Int event so that ASP.NET can load the ViewState data later into Page Control tree (which you will need to access the values from TextBox)

On a side not you should use Dynamic control only when the type of control is dynamic. Else you can achive the same using Repeater and listview

[Truely Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/10/16/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-4_2900_.aspx)

And here is the alternative to using Dynamic controls

[ASP.NET: Alternatives to Dynamic Controls - Part 1](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2008/10/19/asp.net-alternatives-to-dynamic-controls---part-1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!!! And also for the links! Yes, I'm using a table which would normally have only a couple of rows, but I'll look into changing this into a ListView.

Answer (score 3):

You need to contruct dynamic controls on the `Page_Init` event. Are you perhaps doing this in `Page_Load` or elsewhere. If they are added later than `Page_Init` then they don't participate in ViewState which will cause problems.